# How can I convert a list of objects to XElement C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I convert a list of objects to XElement or XMLDocument C#

With no loop

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
XElement element = new XElement("yourNewXElement", YourList);
```

Comment: The idea is to convert each attribute of the object in nodes in the XML

Comment: Well that's a horse of a different color!